# Negating the ?& JSON operator

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Is there a way to negate the `?&` operator in Postgres? The [operators table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) in the postgres docs says that `?&`is equivelent to "Do all of these key/element string exist?"

What I want to do is return rows based on whether all keys in an array do not exist. So something like

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE NEGATE_THIS(jsoncolumn ?& ['v1', 'v2'])
```

I can't see a specific operator in the documents, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about (assuming you want all rows where none of the keys exist)

```
WHERE NOT (jsoncolumn ?| ['v1', 'v2'])
```

`?|` is "Do any of these key/element strings exist?"

Comment: Oh wow, that was so simple. Thanks! Will mark it when the timers finished.